# Клавиатура EditText time

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть EditText в который нужно писать время, пишу  android:inputType="time" на планшете вызывается числовая  клавиатура без двоеточия. Как добавить двоеточие на клавиатуру ?

Comment: Клавиатура - такая же программа, как и любая другая. Разработчики ПО для вашего планшета(если клавиатура стандартная) просто забыли(забили?) сделать отдельный вариант для ввода времени.

Answer (score 2):

`inputType` — лишь пожелание для клавиатуры, но не обязательное к исполнению требование. Если установленная клавиатура не обрабатывает этот флаг, или интерпретирует его по-своему, то это на её совести и поделать с этим ничего не удастся.

Как вариант, вы можете установить `TextWatcher` для вашего `EditText` и в нём обрабатывать ввод первых двух символов, добавляя символ двоеточия вручную.

*Updated:*

Есть способ и проще: напишите реализацию `InputFilter`, в которой будут выполняться необходимые преобразования, после чего назначьте его вызовом `editText.setFilters`.

Answer (score 1):

Реализация InputFilter с вводом чисел от "00:00" до "29:59":

```
timeFilter = new InputFilter() { // фильтр ввода. позволяет вводить от 00:00 до 23:59
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest,
                               int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source.length() > 1 && !doneOnce) {
            source = source.subSequence(source.length() - 1, source.length());
            if (source.charAt(0) >= '0' && source.charAt(0) <= '2') { // первый символ может быть 0,1,2
                doneOnce = true; //флаг первого символа в editText
                return source;
            } else {
                return ""; //остальные символы будут зануляться
            }
        }
        if (source.length() == 0) {
            return null;// deleting, keep original editing
        }
        String result = "";
        result += dest.toString().substring(0, dstart);
        result += source.toString().substring(start, end);
        result += dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length());
        if (result.length() > 5) { // если в поле 5 символов( 1 2 : 4 5 )
            return "";// не разрешать добавлять символы
        }
        boolean allowEdit = true;
        char c;
        if (result.length() > 0) {
            c = result.charAt(0);
            allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '2');
        }
        if (result.length() > 1) {
            c = result.charAt(1);
            if (result.charAt(0) == '0' || result.charAt(0) == '1')
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            else
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '3');
        }
        if (result.length() > 2) {
            c = result.charAt(2);
            allowEdit &= (c == ':');
        }
        if (result.length() > 3) {
            c = result.charAt(3);
            allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '5');
        }
        if (result.length() > 4) {
            c = result.charAt(4);
            allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
        }
        return allowEdit ? null : "";
    }
};
```

[вот мой вопрос, но в вопросе рабочий код, он же здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524958/edittext-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB)

Answer (score 0):

> на планшете вызывается числовая клавиатура без двоеточия

Полагаю, он двоеточие поставит сам после двух цифр. Зачем вводить лишнее?