# EditText: Постоянный не удаляемый символ

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Не пойму, как лучше сделать реализацию задачи в `InputFilter`?

Есть поле `EditText`. В него нужно вводить время в 24-часовом формате.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы **двоеточие** между цифрами часов и минут, **всегда изначально стояло**, типа так:

`"__:__" -> "1_:__" -> "12:__" -> "12:3_" -> "12:34"`

А удаление чтоб шло в таком порядке:

`"12:34" -> "12:3_" -> "12:__" -> "1_:__" -> "__:__"`

Сейчас я ввожу данные цифр и сам подставляю ":".

Я нашёл тут решения, как проверкой в `TextWatcher` добавлять двоеточие программно, по достижении длины строки = 2, но мне не это нужно. Нужно, чтобы двоеточие всегда стояло в `EditText` и при вводе первых 2-х чисел, указатель перепрыгивал это двоеточие и я смог бы дописать остальные 2 числа. И так же мог бы удалять числа, не удаляя двоеточие.

Как понял, нужно изначально записывать в `EditText` два пробела, двоеточие и ещё два пробела, чтоб двоеточие было в центре (текст выравнивается внутри поля ввода), потом при вводе текста как-то проверять и заменять пробел на цифру.

Сейчас у меня есть реализация `InputFilter` с вводом чисел от "00:00" до "29:59":

```
timeFilter = new InputFilter() { // фильтр ввода. позволяет вводить от 00:00 до 23:59
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest,
                                   int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source.length() > 1 && !doneOnce) {
                source = source.subSequence(source.length() - 1, source.length());
                if (source.charAt(0) >= '0' && source.charAt(0) <= '2') { // первый символ может быть 0,1,2
                    doneOnce = true; //флаг первого символа в editText
                    return source;
                } else {
                    return ""; //остальные символы будут зануляться
                }
            }
            if (source.length() == 0) {
                return null;// deleting, keep original editing
            }
            String result = "";
            result += dest.toString().substring(0, dstart);
            result += source.toString().substring(start, end);
            result += dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length());
            if (result.length() > 5) { // если в поле 5 символов( 1 2 : 4 5 )
                return "";// не разрешать добавлять символы
            }
            boolean allowEdit = true;
            char c;
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                c = result.charAt(0);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '2');
            }
            if (result.length() > 1) {
                c = result.charAt(1);
                if (result.charAt(0) == '0' || result.charAt(0) == '1')
                    allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
                else
                    allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '3');
            }
            if (result.length() > 2) {
                c = result.charAt(2);
                allowEdit &= (c == ':');
            }
            if (result.length() > 3) {
                c = result.charAt(3);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '5');
            }
            if (result.length() > 4) {
                c = result.charAt(4);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            }
            return allowEdit ? null : "";
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне рабочим вариантом будет составление разметки из `EditText` + `TextView` + `EditText`.

- По середине будет ваше двоеточие.
- Слушатели ввода в `EditText` будут проверять длину введённого/стёртого и перекидывать фокус на другой `EditText`

Comment: а тогда мне придётся 2 разных фильтра для полей сделать?

Comment: @zayn1991, да, но наверняка будет проще. К тому же, вроде, можно в свойствах поля ввода прописать что ему можно вводить, а что нет. Типа только цмфры. Уже проще будет)

Comment: ладно, сдамся со своей идеей одного editText'а и сделаю, как Вы предложили)